# Filter in custom arrayadapter not showing any result; it is not filtering the data

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, android-arrayadapter

There are no errors when i hit enter but there is no change also the filter is not working. it seems to be all right but i don't know whats going wrong. Please answer, i would really appreciate that 
ArrayAdapter-

```
package com.paradise.android.french.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.paradise.android.french.R;
import com.paradise.android.french.pojo.word;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class wordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<word> implements Filterable {

private int ColorResourceid;
private List<word> filterWords;
private Filter valueFilter;
List<word> Words;

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}


public wordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<word> words, int colorResourceId) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    ColorResourceid = colorResourceId;
    Words = words;
    filterWords = words;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    word currentWord = getItem(position);

    TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.french);
    miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getFrenchWord());

    TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.english);
    defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getEngWord());

    View colorit = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.havecolor);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), ColorResourceid);
    colorit.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return listItemView;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {

            ArrayList<word> filterList = new ArrayList<word>();

            for (int i = 0; i < filterWords.size(); i++) {

                if ((filterWords.get(i).getEngWord().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    word Word = new word(filterWords.get(i).getEngWord(), filterWords.get(i).getFrenchWord(), filterWords.get(i).getmediaPlayer());

                    filterList.add(Word);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        }else {
            results.count = filterWords.size();
            results.values = filterWords;
        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        Words = (ArrayList<word>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Words.size();
}

}
```

Fragment:

```
package com.paradise.android.french.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.paradise.android.french.R;
import com.paradise.android.french.pojo.word;
import com.paradise.android.french.adapter.wordAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Accommodation extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;
private wordAdapter adapter;

private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {

            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {

            mMediaPlayer.start();

        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {

            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};

public static Accommodation newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    Accommodation fragment = new Accommodation();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, container, false);

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    final ArrayList<word> fte = new ArrayList<word>();
    fte.add(new word("I will stay for nights", "Je vais rester des nuits", R.raw.accomodation_iwillstayherefornights));
    fte.add(new word("May i see the room first", "Puis-je voir la chambre d'abord", R.raw.accommodation_mayiseetherromfirst));
    fte.add(new word("Is breakfast included", "Le petit déjeuner est-il inclus", R.raw.accommodation_isbreakfastincluded));
    fte.add(new word("I have a reservation", "J'ai une reservation", R.raw.accommodation_ihaveareservation));
    fte.add(new word("Do you have rooms available", "Avez-vous des chambres disponibles", R.raw.accommodation_doyouhaveroomsavailable));
    fte.add(new word("I have locked myself out of my room", "Je me suis enfermé dans ma chamber", R.raw.accommodation_ihavelockedmyselfoutoftheroom));
    fte.add(new word("What time is checkout", "A quelle heure est la caisse?", R.raw.accommodation_whattimeischeckout));

    adapter = new wordAdapter(getActivity(), fte, R.color.accommodation);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();

            word word = fte.get(position);

            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), word.getmediaPlayer());
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)      MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item2);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#5D4037">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="About"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_support"
    android:title="Support"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_36pt"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try update the `Words` your `ArrayAdapter` currently reference to, instead of assigning another `List` (i.e. `results.values`) to `Words`.

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    Words.clear();
    Words.addAll((List<word>) results.values);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```